# Tracking the Bounced Emails or undelivered emails sent through Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

Im trying to send an html email with attachment to list of users. Our client also requires the track of undelivered email ids, so we thought of using sp_send_dbmail feature available in SQL server, which has logs for email sent using it. Our client also mandate to DKIM sign the emails. Im not able to find how to DKIM sign the emails sent through sp_send_dbmail.

Please help!..

Answer (score 1):

Normally DKIM signing is a SMTP server business, not SQL. You want to talk to postmaster. There are several steps involved in enabling DKIM signing outgoing email:

1. Generation of RSA crypto key pair
2. Publication of public key in DNS (so receiving server is able to verify the signature)
3. Setting up signing service
4. Modifying your SMTP server configuration to use this signing service for all or specific outgoing emails

There are third party controls that enable signing from within SQL, but not using sp_send_dbmail. See here for example: http://www.example-code.com/sql/dkim_sendDkimSigned.asp
However they don't eliminate the 1 and 2 above.